# Vanilla JavaScript: how to keep track of the circle in canvas on specific path?

Tags: javascript, canvas

everyone I have following code I want the filled circle to remain within the drawn path or dont slip out of the curved (although it can) if it happens the game ends, (I don't want to bound it to the path) I have been working on this can't help myself finding a solution.

one more thing I want the filled circle initial position right on either end of the curved path thanks any input or help is appreciated thanks

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var x = 0;
        var y = 250;
        var radius = 10;
        var pathWidth = 200;
        var pathHeight = 100;
        var pathStartX = 100;
        var pathStartY = 200;
        var pathEndX = 400;
        var pathEndY = 200;
        var pathControlX = 250;
        var pathControlY = 100;
        var pathControlX2 = 250;
        var pathControlY2 = 300;
        var pathColor = "black";
        var circleColor = "red";
        var score = 0;
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        var endTime = startTime + 60000;
        var path = new Path2D();
        path.moveTo(pathStartX, pathStartY);
        path.bezierCurveTo(pathControlX, pathControlY, pathControlX2, pathControlY2, pathEndX, pathEndY);
        context.stroke(path);
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = circleColor;
        context.fill();
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            x = event.clientX - rect.left;
            y = event.clientY - rect.top;
        });
        function draw() {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.stroke(path);
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            context.fillStyle = circleColor;
            context.fill();
            if (x > pathEndX - radius && x < pathEndX + radius && y > pathEndY - radius && y < pathEndY + radius) {
                score++;
                pathStartX = pathEndX;
                pathStartY = pathEndY;
                pathEndX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width - pathWidth)) + pathWidth;
                pathEndY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.height - pathHeight)) + pathHeight;
                pathControlX = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
                pathControlY = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
                pathControlX2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
                pathControlY2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
                path = new Path2D();
                path.moveTo(pathStartX, pathStartY);
                path.bezierCurveTo(pathControlX, pathControlY, pathControlX2, pathControlY2, pathEndX, pathEndY);
                context.stroke(path);
                x = pathStartX;
                y = pathStartY;
            }
            if (new Date().getTime() > endTime) {
                alert("Game Over! Your score is " + score);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }
        var interval = setInterval(draw, 10);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been working on this can't help myself finding a solution

Answer (score 0):

A little update:

```html
 <style>
  #canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
<div id="msg"> Waiting</div>
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
  var gameStarted = false,
    negscore = 0;
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var radius = 20;
  var pathWidth = 200;
  var pathHeight = 100;
  var pathStartX = 100;
  var pathStartY = 200;
  var pathEndX = 400;
  var pathEndY = 200;
  var pathControlX = 250;
  var pathControlY = 100;
  var pathControlX2 = 250;
  var pathControlY2 = 300;
  var pathColor = "black";
  var circleColor = "red";
  var score = 0;
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var endTime = startTime + 20000;
  var path = new Path2D();
  path.moveTo(pathStartX, pathStartY);
  path.bezierCurveTo(
    pathControlX,
    pathControlY,
    pathControlX2,
    pathControlY2,
    pathEndX,
    pathEndY
  );
  context.stroke(path);
  context.lineWidth = 40;
  x = pathStartX;
  y = pathStartY;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = circleColor;
  context.fill();
  var mouseTravelDistance = 0;
  var prevMouseX = x;
  var prevMouseY = y;

  function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.stroke(path);
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = circleColor;
    context.fill();
    if (gameStarted) {
      if (
        x > pathEndX - radius &&
        x < pathEndX + radius &&
        y > pathEndY - radius &&
        y < pathEndY + radius
      ) {
        score++;
        pathStartX = pathEndX;
        pathStartY = pathEndY;
        pathEndX =
          Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width - pathWidth)) + pathWidth;
        pathEndY =
          Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.height - pathHeight)) +
          pathHeight;
        pathControlX = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        pathControlY = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
        pathControlX2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        pathControlY2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
        path = new Path2D();
        path.moveTo(pathStartX, pathStartY);
        path.bezierCurveTo(
          pathControlX,
          pathControlY,
          pathControlX2,
          pathControlY2,
          pathEndX,
          pathEndY
        );
        context.stroke(path);
        x = pathStartX;
        y = pathStartY;
      }
      if (new Date().getTime() > endTime || context.isPointInStroke(path, x, y) === false) {
        alert(
          "Game Over! Your score is " +
          score +
          ". Mouse travel distance: " +
          mouseTravelDistance.toFixed(2) +
          "px" + " | Negative : " + negscore
        );
        clearInterval(interval);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }
    }
  }
  var interval = setInterval(draw, 10);
  canvas.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (context.isPointInPath(path, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
      gameStarted = true;
      canvas.style.cursor = "default";
      canvas.removeEventListener("click", arguments.callee);
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Game Started";
    }
  });
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    if (gameStarted) {
      var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      x = event.clientX - rect.left;
      y = event.clientY - rect.top;
      mouseTravelDistance += Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(x - prevMouseX, 2) + Math.pow(y - prevMouseY, 2)
      );
      prevMouseX = x;
      prevMouseY = y;
    } else if (!gameStarted) {
      if (context.isPointInPath(path, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
        canvas.style.cursor = "pointer";
      } else {
        canvas.style.cursor = "default";
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

the code now does what was initially required